# testing nodejs cluster with apache benchmark

Tags: node.js, apachebench

These days I am interested in nodejs cluster module to implement multi processing.

Here is the code which would help to explain my issue.

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1;

const cluster = require('cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster){

    cluster.fork();
    cluster.fork();

} else {
    const express = require('express');
    const crypto = require('crypto');

    const app = express();

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
       crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
           res.send('benchmark test');
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('listen on port 3000');
    });
}
```

I've set `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` to 1 for simplicity (default by 4)

I am using 2017 macbook pro which is dual core machine with 4 threads(logical cores)

and the `pbkdf2` function inside of that code takes about 1 second to be processed in my computer. (more precisely, 970ms)

I am using apache benchmark to test the performance, but having some confusion.

with the command,

```
ab -c 4 -n 4 localhost:3000/

Time taken for tests:   1.785 seconds
Complete requests:      4
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      840 bytes
HTML transferred:       44 bytes
Requests per second:    2.24 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1785.403 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       446.351 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)


Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:  1769 1779   7.1   1783    1785
Waiting:     1769 1779   7.3   1783    1785
Total:       1769 1779   7.1   1783    1785
```

my computer has two cores (physcial cores), and there are two nodejs instances(clusters).

so I thought one core would take one instance.

so when four requests come into play at the same time,

I assumed that first 2 requests must be processed, and last 2 requests must be processed.

but 4 requests are processed at the same time, and connection time of min and max are almost same.

Any advice would really be appreciated.